# In Excel VBA, how do I find a substring, select the rest of the column below it, then move the selected area to another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

UPDATE: I realized that A1 has a keyword I'm looking for, which I didn't see and caused the issue that came up.

I need to find a word - "P/position", "S/site", or "Residue," then copy everything in the column below this to a column in a sheet in a different workbook ("ExtractedColumns," "Sheet1"). I was able to do all of this with the first two blocks of code in my macro - I was looking for different words and pasted to different columns, but it worked for those. And when I ran the following code on a different sheet, it worked. However, the following code copies everything in column A starting from A2, but the substring it was supposed to locate was in column E- so it was supposed to copy from E5 and below. So why does this block of code select from a completely different column?
("curr" is a range)

```
For Each curr In Range("A1:S10")
    If InStr(1, curr.Value, "residue") > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "Residue") > 0 Or InStr(curr.Value, "Position") > 0 Or InStr(curr.Value, "position") > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "Site") > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "site") > 0 Then
    Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2")
        Exit For
    End If
    Set curr = curr.Offset(1)
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested it, works fine for me. Are you sure that A1 does not contain any of the strings you are searching for?

Two small things: if you want inStr to work case-insensitive, you can set the compare-parameter to vbTextCompare, e.g.

```
InStr(1, curr.Value, "residue", vbTextCompare)
```

Secondly, what is the 6th line for? The for-loop iterates through all cells in the range, why do you manually change it to the next cell?

Comment: I found that line fishy as well, `Set curr = curr.Offset(1)` and was investigating it, but it turns out it has no effect. Welcome aboard :)

Comment: BTW, to use vbTextCompare OP should also include the first paraneter (`1`) which was omitted in `InStr(curr.Value, "Position")` --> `InStr(1, curr.Value, "position", vbTextCompare)`.

Comment: @A.S.H 'Set curr = curr.Offset(1)' changes the value of curr by one row.

Comment: @Caltor yes, I'm saying it has no effect on the surrounding `For Each` loop.

Comment: @A.S.H It looks like it would totally screw things up to me.

Comment: @Caltor it didn't affect the loop in my (simplified) test. If you see something else it would be useful to elaborate on it.

Comment: @JanB Thanks for trying it, and for the advice about vbTextCompare. I realized that the problem is that A1, which is the title of the table, has one of the key words ("site") at the end, so that's why my code wasn't working as planned.

Comment: @A.S.H I've only got my iPad to hand at the moment so I have to admit you have a march on me there having actually tested it. However as curr is the current element in the A1:S10 range being enumerated, changing its value inside of the foreach loop seems pretty dangerous to me. I would expect the results to be undefined. I wouldn't be surprised if the loop went diagonally across the sheet! I dont see what that line of code is even doing in there.

Comment: @caltor - I **suspect** (but have no proof) that, unlike a `For i =` loop where the loop index is accessible to the code (i.e. the variable `i`), a `For Each obj In` loop maintains an internal index to which object it is up to.  Changing the object `obj` itself doesn't affect the index which will be used to assign the next iteration's `obj`.  Certainly the `Set curr = curr.Offset(1)` in the OP's code does no harm, but nor does it do any good, and it would definitely be a good idea to remove it.

Comment: @YowE3K You're totally right! The "Technical Implementation" section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx states "If your statement block changes element or group, these changes don't affect the iteration of the loop." but does add "You might want to avoid changing the value of element inside a loop. Doing this can make it more difficult to read and debug your code.". It's talking about full blown VB but I think the same applies to VBA.

Comment: @Caltor - I cringe every time I see code that changes the loop variable, irrespective of whether it is a `For i = ...` loop or a `For Each x In ...` loop.  It makes it **very** hard to keep track of what is happening.  I'm glad Microsoft has added that warning in their documentation.